# How to output reactive data

Tags: r, shiny

I am using Shiny and want to output some of the data.

This is the code I am using to load data and select variables

```
  data.feature <-  reactive({
    # filename <- paste0("dataall_'", input$date, "'new.RData")
    filename <- paste0("dataall_new.RData")
    load(filename)
    feature.test[input$variable,]
  })
```

Then use the following code to download the data

```
 output$downloadDatar <- downloadHandler(
    filename = paste('data_summary.RData'),
    content = function(file) {
      save( data.feature, file= file)})  
    }})
```

But when I open the saved file, and enter data.feature I got this:

```
reactive({
    filename <- paste0("dataall_new.RData")
    load(filename)
    feature.test[input$variable]
})
```

Is there any way to view the data inside?

BTW, I tried data.feature() in save function and got  `object ‘data.feature()’ not found` error

Problem solved: just use isolate function

Comment: I suggest posting an answer with your solution, this will help others having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: just use isolate function